# How do you determine which terms to call intros on in coq

Tags: coq

I am a beginner with coq, so this may be a trivial question. Sometimes I can't figure out which terms I need to call intros on, when writing a Theorem. A simple example,

```
Theorem silly1 : forall (n m o p : nat),
  n = m  ->
  [n;o] = [n;p] ->
  [n;o] = [m;p].
Proof.
  intros n m o p eq1 eq2.
  rewrite <- eq1.
  apply eq2.  Qed.
```

I know based on the goal, that I will probably need to call intros on (n m o p), but why do I need to use it on eq1 and eq2.

Also, in some other Theorems, you may need to use intros on the type parameter, the hypothesis, or the inductive hypothesis. Example

```
Theorem trans_eq : forall (X:Type) (n m o : X),
  n = m -> m = o -> n = o.
Proof.
  intros X n m o eq1 eq2. rewrite -> eq1. rewrite -> eq2. 
  reflexivity.  Qed.

Theorem silly3' : forall (n : nat),
  (beq_nat n 5 = true -> beq_nat (S (S n)) 7 = true) ->
  true = beq_nat n 5  ->
  true = beq_nat (S (S n)) 7.
Proof.
  intros n eq H.
  symmetry in H. apply eq in H. symmetry in H. 
  apply H.  Qed.
```

So I guess what I'm asking is...when I start proving a theorem, how should I go about reasoning through the goals, to determine which terms I need to call intros on?

Comment: If you introduce too many arguments, the worst that can happen is that the generated proof term is [`eta`-expanded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_expansion#.CE.B7-conversion). It's not problematic.

Answer (score 3):

An example of what gallais is refering to is this.

```
Theorem example_1 : forall A B, (A -> B) -> A -> B.
Proof. intros ? ? H1. apply H1. Qed.

Theorem example_2 : forall A B, (A -> B) -> A -> B.
Proof. intros ? ? H1 H2. apply H1. apply H2. Qed.

Print example_1.
Print example_2.
```

Another example of when it can be problematic is using introduction before using induction. This makes the induction hypothesis different.

```
Fixpoint reverse_helper {A : Type} (l1 l2 : list A) : list A :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => l2
  | cons x l1 => reverse_helper l1 (cons x l2)
  end.

Theorem example_3 : forall A (l1 l2 : list A), reverse_helper l1 l2 = app (reverse_helper l1 nil) l2.
Proof. intros. induction l1. simpl. reflexivity. simpl. try rewrite IHl1. Abort.

Theorem example_4 : forall A (l1 l2 : list A), reverse_helper l1 l2 = app (reverse_helper l1 nil) l2.
Proof. induction l1. intros. simpl. reflexivity. intros. simpl. rewrite (IHl1 (cons a l2)). rewrite (IHl1 (cons a nil)). Admitted.
```

Otherwise, you should use introduction whenever you can. You won't be able to use whatever is being quantified over or the antecedents of an implication until you do.

By the way

```
H1 : A1
...
Hn : An
___
B
```

is equivalent to

```
H1: A1, ..., Hn: An ⊢ B.
```

When you prove something interactively, you're using a sequent calculus starting from the conclusion and working your way back to the hypotheses.